# Why Does re.sub() Not Work in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, regex, ascii, python-re, non-ascii-characters

I'm working on a project where I have to read data from an Excel spreadsheet. I'm using Python.

I noticed when I use "re.sub()" the characters in the original string are not replaced. When I use "string.replace()" the characters from the original string get replaced, but not when I'm using "re.sub()."

I'm wondering if I'm doing something wrong.
Could anyone please check this on your end?

Technical Details:

- Python version: 3.6.
- Operating System: Windows 10
- Libraries to install: openpyxl
- [UTF-8 codes](https://www.charset.org/utf-8)
- [Unicode for emojis](https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/emoji/emoji-data.txt)

This is what I originally had:

```
string = re.sub(u'([\u2000-\u206f])', " ", string)
string = re.sub(u'(\u00a0)', " ", string)

string = string.replace("‰", " ") #\u0089
string = string.replace("¤", " ") #\u00a4
```

Following "chepner"'s advice, I changed the logic to the following:

```
replacementDict = {}
replacementDict.update(dict.fromkeys(map(chr, range(0x2000, 0x206f)), " "))
replacementDict['\u00a0'] = " "
replacementDict['\u0089'] = " "
replacementDict['\u00a4'] = " "

string = string.translate(replacementDict)
```

But I'm still not able to remove the illegal characters from the string.

You can download the script and a sample test [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/tfpcdc5fu2z9htu/min_mock_re_sub.zip/file):

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Run the script as-is (removed the need to send parameters to the script), you will notice the lines that did not match are the ones with illegal characters.

Comment: The code as-is doesn't do anything, and frankly it is quite massive. Please take a look at the [mre] help page and [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: Issues aside, you are making far more calls to `re.sub` than you need. `string = re.sub('[\u2000-\u206f\u00a0\u1680\u180e\ufeff\u00ad]', ' ', string)` would be sufficient, for example.

Comment: The capture groups are also unnecessary, since you aren't making references to them in the substitution text.

Comment: You don't even need regular expressions for this. You can use `str.translate` to map single characters to their replacements.

Comment: To reiterate: The question is closed because it has no [mre] to reproduce your problem. That includes *sample* input and expected/actual output. The most recent edits only serve to invalidate the existing answer, which is contrary to the point of [so]. If you cannot get an answer to work, *comment* on it instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would replace all this with a single call to `str.translate`, since you are only making single-character-to-single-character replacements.

You'll just need to define a single `dict` (that you can reused for every call to `str.translate`) that maps each character to its replacement. Characters that stay the same do not need to be added to the mapping.

```
replacements = {}
replacements.update(dict.fromkeys(range(0x2000, 0x2070), " "))
replacements[0x1680] = ' '
# etc

string = string.translate(replacements)
```

You can also use `str.maketrans` to construct an appropriate translation table from a char-to-char mapping.

Comment: Hello chepner. Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. I tried your solution, but it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: The replacement map must contain the ordinals, not the characters. (I always mess that up too ) E.g. ``replacements[0x1680] = ' '``. One could also use ``str.maketrans`` to on the current ``replacements`` to do that automatically.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently, I've never constructed the mapping for `str.translate` by hand.